# Arduino Due conditional compilation constant for custom library

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm writing a custom library and it is working correctly on an Arduino Uno.  However I've now got my hands on an Arduino Due and I need to define some board specific pin constants.

I know for most boards you can do this through an `#ifdef` directive using the IO constants defined in `\\arduino-1.5.2\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h`.  For instance:

```
#if defined (__AVR_ATmega128__)
    //do something specific
#endif
```

Does anybody know which is the correct constant to use for the Due?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically use ...

```
#ifndef __AVR__
// something special just for non AVR8's
// ...
#endif
```

Where as I believe you could also use...

```
#ifdef _SAM3XA_
// something special just for Due's SAM3XA
// ...
#endif
```

Comment: `_SAM3XA_` is the one (not sure why only one underscore!). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `_SAM3XA_` will work, but includes a lot of other Atmel ARM chips (SAM3X8C, SAM3X8H, etc.).

Something more precise would be

```
#if defined (__arm__) && defined (__SAM3X8E__) // Arduino Due compatible
// your Arduino Due compatible code here
#endif
```

(See the file [sam3.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/ide-1.5.x/hardware/arduino/sam/system/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3.h) for more info.)

If you just want to target the Arduino Due (leaving out compatible boards), you can use

```
#if defined (_VARIANT_ARDUINO_DUE_X_)
// your Arduino Due code here
#endif
```

(This is defined in the Arduino Due's [variant.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/ide-1.5.x/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.h) file.)